# Manage Unit price unit - Prestashop

Tags: prestashop

i need to use the price unit ratio in product page.
But i just need de suffix without the ratio price.

Example : 2€ per KG

I just want to use KG

The prestashop query includes the both (price and suffix)

```
{l s='%unit_price%' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog' sprintf=['%unit_price%' => $product.unit_price_full]}
```

How can i divise this combination.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved**

The solution :

replace $product.unit_price_full -> $product.unity

```
{l s='%unit_price%' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog' sprintf=['%unit_price%' => $product.unity]}
```